# Why does iTerm paste when I left click in the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, mouse, iterm2

Every so often I come back to a iTerm2 (v3.1.6) terminal window and for whatever reason when I left click anywhere in the window it will paste whatever is on my clipboard. This has happened many times now (10+)

This appears to be similar to how the middle mouse button works, but for the left mouse button.

Additionally, I am unable to select any text and the middle mouse button does not paste while this is happening.

The only way I can disable this functionality is to close the window and open a new one.

I am using macOS High Sierra (10.13.3)

Comment: I didnt think there would be any relevant screenshots/logs I could provide, let me know if there is anything in particular I should add

Comment: What actions do you have in Preferences > Pointer tab ?

Comment: @harrymc, just the defaults (I reset to be sure). I just noticed the triple click to emulate mouse button option, Ill try disabling that next time it happens

Comment: Nice work on finding a workaround, this was potentially dangerous when working in production. Someone else has bugged it with the project https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/7586

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by disabling "Three finger tap emulates middle click".

I verified by waiting until the issue came up again and then disabling the feature which fixed the issue and didn't require me to restart the session. Im not sure why it starts to register single taps as three finger taps.

Comment: As of the latest version (3.3.12) it no longer respects this setting, and a single tap still causes it to paste. iTerm2, why? A mouse should NEVER paste.

Answer (score 1):

On ITerm2 v3.4.3

Go to `Preferences` -> `Pointer` -> `Bindings` -> `Highlight "Paste from Clipboard"` -> `press '-'` to delete.

Seemed to solve it for me.